# How do I purchase an admission to Jasper national park in Canada?

Tags: canada, planning, national-parks

I am shortly travelling to Canada to do an RV trip with my wife. The middle itinerary looks like:

```
Day 5 - Arrive in Jasper & stay in Waipiti Campsite for 2 nights
Day 7 - Move to A Campsite in Rampart Creek
Day 8 - Move to Lake Louise Campsite for 2 nights
```

I've read a lot both [here on the official parks website](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/ab/jasper/visit/tarifs-fees) and on [multiple](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Jasper_National_Park) [other](http://banffandbeyond.com/understanding-the-parks-canada-entry-fees/) websites that I need to buy a pass. I have no problem with that.

What I'm confused about is when I actually buy the pass, and whether I need multiple for the different stays. I have already booked my campsites in the three locations due to the size of the RV.

**So My Question Is:** How & When Do I buy passes for the Canadian national parks?

Comment: Your last link has a whole section about "Where Can I Buy A Park Pass In the Canadian Rockies" which contains a list of all the locations.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @MichaelHampton _shamelessly steals the answer_. Thanks Michael you are helping me win the Answerathon competition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](http://banffandbeyond.com/understanding-the-parks-canada-entry-fees/), park passes can be purchased in one of the several kiosks and park offices scattered around the parks, as well as online. Quoting from the link:

> ## Where Can I Buy A Park Pass In the Canadian Rockies
>
> There are several entry gates that have kiosks manned with park attendants.
>
> #### Westbound
>
> - East Banff gate – this is where you enter Banff National Park when driving west from Calgary or Canmore on Trans-Canada Highway #1. If you have already purchased a park pass you don’t have to stop at this gate each time. Slow down to the posted speed limit and drive by in the pass-through lane.
> - Jasper East Park – This is the gate you will approach when heading west from Hinton or Edmonton on the Yellowhead Highway #16
>
> #### Eastbound
>
> - Kootenay West Gate – used when driving in from Radium Hotsprings or Cranbrook on the Banff-Windermere Highway #93
> - Jasper West Gate – used when driving in from Kamloops or Prince George on the Yellowhead Highway #16
>     Icefields Parkway – There are pass kiosks located at each end of the Icefields Parkway near Lake Louise and Jasper.
>
> ### Parks Canada Tourist Office Locations
>
> If you have entered a park where there was not a gate or the gate was unattended you need to head to one of the following locations to purchase a pass.
>
> - Lake Louise – next to the Samson Mall in the village of Lake Louise
> - Banff – in the town at 224 Banff Avenue
> - Jasper – in town at 500 Connaught Drive
> - Yoho – at the Field Visitor Center on the Trans Canada Hwy (May to early October only) use the Lake Louise location the rest of the year.
> - Kootenay – (May to September only) in the village of Radium on the main street
>
> Additional places to purchase park passes in Banff National Park
>
> - Wilson Mountain Sports – in the Samson Mall in the village of Lake Louise
>
> ### Purchase Online Or By Phone
>
> You can purchase an annual Discovery Pass prior to your trip online or by phone. Call 403-760-1343 or 1-888-773-8888 between 8am and 4pm M.S.T. (Mountain Standard Time) or online at: [Parks Canada Annual Discovery Park Pass](http://www.commandesparcs-parksorders.ca/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/parksb2c/discovery-pass). Daily or Discovery Park Passes can be also be purchased online at [Banff/Lake Louise Tourism](https://parkpass.banfflakelouise.com/)